# SVG Path On Click Event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, arrays

Referring to the code-snipplet below about getting data with on click on an svg path [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73508160/getting-data-on-click-on-button-with-svg-path), for my example which is displaying Number 2, **I would like it to have the alert button pop up when the cursor is clicked only when close to number 2**. My code below is wrong because when cursor is clicked anywhere which is far way from the Number 2, the pop up alert box is still shown. I will really appreciate any help I can get :)

```js
function getKey(button) {
 let key = button.querySelectorAll('path')[0].dataset.key;
 alert('key is ' + key)
}
```

```html
<div onClick="getKey(this)">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="800pt" height="600pt" viewBox="0 0 800 600 " id="svg1">
  <g enable-background="new">
    <path data-key="12345" transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,0,600)" stroke-width=".74" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 224.34 585.57 L 224.34 586.6 L 225.22 588.68 L 226.1 589.71 L 227.87 590.75 L 231.39 590.75 L 233.15 589.71 L 234.04 588.68 L 234.92 586.6 L 234.92 584.53 L 234.04 582.46 L 232.27 579.35 L 223.46 568.98 L 235.8 568.98 "/>
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Your click event is attached to the div containing the svg and will fire when  any area inside the div is clicked. The argument `this` will ALWAYS be the div. Once fired, regardless of where the click occurred, the handler function extracts the data attribute of the first path tag beneath the div. You need to use event listeners rather than onclick attributes and either make them specific to `path`s or determine that the target of the event is a path before extracting the data attribute from the target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`this` in an element `onclick` attribute refers to the element**

By setting an `onclick` attribute to the `div` containing the `svg`, a click anywhere within the `div` will call the function, and if `this` is sent to the function as an argument, it will always refer to the `div` element.

Once fired, your function is extracting the data attribute of the first `path` tag inside the `div`.

Instead, an `eventListener` can be attached to the `path` elements directly. When fired an `event` is created, which has a `target` property containing a reference to the tag that generated the event. It is that `target` element from which you need to extract the `data` attribute.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

This working snippet demonstrates attaching event listeners to your paths. (I have had to change the line width of your path as the click must hit the line for the event to be triggered, see end note)

```js
let paths = document.querySelectorAll('path');
// paths is an html collection of all paths;
// attach event listeners to each path;
for (let i=0; i<paths.length; i++) {
  paths[i].addEventListener('click', event => alert(event.target.dataset.key));
}
```

```html
<div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="800pt" height="600pt" viewBox="0 0 800 600 " id="svg1">
  <g enable-background="new">
    <path data-key="12345" transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,0,600)" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 224.34 585.57 L 224.34 586.6 L 225.22 588.68 L 226.1 589.71 L 227.87 590.75 L 231.39 590.75 L 233.15 589.71 L 234.04 588.68 L 234.92 586.6 L 234.92 584.53 L 234.04 582.46 L 232.27 579.35 L 223.46 568.98 L 235.8 568.98 "/>
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

If you have many paths, the above process may not be memory-efficient because the function is duplicated for each of the paths. Instead, a single handler function can be used and called from each of the event listeners. Like this:

```js
let paths = document.querySelectorAll('path');
// paths is an html collection of all paths;
// attach event listeners to each path;
for (let i=0; i<paths.length; i++) {
  paths[i].addEventListener('click', displayAlert);
} 

function displayAlert(event) {
  alert(event.target.dataset.key)
}
```

```html
<div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="800pt" height="600pt" viewBox="0 0 800 600 " id="svg1">
  <g enable-background="new">
    <path data-key="12345" transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,0,600)" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 224.34 585.57 L 224.34 586.6 L 225.22 588.68 L 226.1 589.71 L 227.87 590.75 L 231.39 590.75 L 233.15 589.71 L 234.04 588.68 L 234.92 586.6 L 234.92 584.53 L 234.04 582.46 L 232.27 579.35 L 223.46 568.98 L 235.8 568.98 "/>
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Note that the `displayAlert` function is referenced within the event listener without parentheses or argument. The event is passed automatically to the named external function (the declaration for which should include an argument if the automatically passed `event` is to be used inside the function). In practice, you are unlikely to have memory problems with such a trivial function but I've included this for completeness.

Alternatively, you can attach a single event listener to the `div`, and check that the `target` of the event is a `path` before displaying the data. This works because, although the event is attached to the `div`, the `target` of the event is set to whichever descendant of the `div` was clicked:

```js
let div = document.getElementById('svg-container');

div.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.tagName == 'path') alert(event.target.dataset.key)
});
```

```html
<div id="svg-container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="800pt" height="600pt" viewBox="0 0 800 600 " id="svg1">
  <g enable-background="new">
    <path data-key="12345" transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,0,600)" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 224.34 585.57 L 224.34 586.6 L 225.22 588.68 L 226.1 589.71 L 227.87 590.75 L 231.39 590.75 L 233.15 589.71 L 234.04 588.68 L 234.92 586.6 L 234.92 584.53 L 234.04 582.46 L 232.27 579.35 L 223.46 568.98 L 235.8 568.98 "/>
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

**note**

If you have to use narrow strokes for your paths, it may be difficult for a user to place the cursor exactly on the line and so clicks may be missed. One way to mitigate this is to duplicate the paths, set the stroke of the the lower (first) one of each pair much wider and make it invisible by using the background colour. In the case of characters like your number 2, it might be simpler to draw an appropriately sized invisible rectangle behind each character and attach event listener to them instead, or as well as, the character paths (remembering to include the data attribute).

Comment: Hi Dave, your answer is so detailed. Thank you for taking the time to answer it. Hope you have a good day, sir!!

Comment: Hi Dave, I have implemented your code in part of my app at https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/GRBVzbd?editors=1010, about this increasing stroke-width and hide it with background color to increase the click area (easier to click), how do I implement it haha? I am pretty confused about this :).

Comment: If you click into my demo, there is number 2 and 5 displayed, and if you were to click on each specific number, it will be highlighted as red color and black colour if clicked again :)

Comment: Well done on getting your colour changes working. You might want to also investigate class toggling (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList and https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp ). If your give your paths a css class attribute and set rules for it, `.classlist.toggle` can be used to apply and remove a second class. It is often a simple way of swapping styles back and forth on an element and it worth learning about it you're not familiar with it.

Comment: Regarding increasing the click area of a path, if you duplicate your path (copy and paste it inside the same svg) and set it's stroke width to, say, 20, the duplicate will obviously have a large area to click but will appear bigger than you want. If you made it invisible, the click area will still be there. Although I suggested using the background colour to make it invisible, it's probably easier to set it to `transparent` to get the same effect. Have a play, you'll be able to work it out. Good luck!