# Can I make DOM events (onMouseOver) trigger on specific SVG paths and not the full SVG element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, svg

I´m practicing React making some apps and in one part I made a SVG map with multiple paths as sections (each one it´s a state of a country); now I want to use functions when triggering the onMouseOver event on every section individually but these trigger whenever I put the pointer over the SVG element like I hovered every path no matter where I position the pointer.

The idea is that whenever hovering a specific SVG path the stateIdContainer component must show the id/name/text of the hovered path and the testShowStateId function must show in the console the same text, but no matter what I hover the console will show the id/name/text of all paths and the component will show the id/name/text of the last path in the DOM tree as if I hovered all three simultaneous.

- All the paths are inside g elements inside an SVG elements so trying stuff like adding event listeners or DOM events to the SVG will not work unless I separate every path in it´s own SVG element.

**App.js content**
(Here's just 2 useStates and 2 components, the components are a small container that shows the id/name/text of the hovered state and the other it´s the SVG map with multiple paths, every path it´s suppoused to be an individual state. The useStates are one used to show or hid the first container whenever an SVG path is hovered and the other saves the hovered state id/name/text)

```
function App() {

  const [displayStateId, stateDisplay] = useState('none');
  const [hoveredStateId, stateId] = useState('placeholder');

  return (
    
    <div>
      <stateIdContainer stateIdText={hoveredStateId} displayContainer={displayStateId} />
      <svgMap currentStateDisplay={displayStateId} nameIsShow={stateDisplay} />
      </div>

  );
}
```

**testShowStateId function**
This is an auxiliar function, originally I will use it to make some axios requests using the values passed as arguments but for simplicity I´m just using a console.log in this example

```
export  function testShowStateId (stateIdText) {
    console.log(stateIdText);
}
```

**stateIdContainer Component**
This is a container element whose function is to appear visible whenever a path of the SVG is hovered and show the state id/name/text of the hovered path

```
export function stateIdContainer(props) {
    return(
    <div >
        <container style={{display: props.displayContainer}}>
            <p>{props.stateIdText}</p>
        </container>
    </div>
    );
}
```

**svgMap componene**
Originally this will be a map of my country with multiple paths, each one being a individual state but for simplicity I just made some simple SVG forms.

```
export function svgMap(props) {

    function toggleShowName() {
        props.currentStateDisplay == 'inline-block'? props.nameIsShow('none') : props.nameIsShow('inline-block');
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <svg width='800' height='800' viewBox="0 0 15 15"  >
                <g onMouseEnter={toggleShowName} onMouseLeave={toggleShowName}> {/*I put the events onMouse* here so they will trigger when hovering only the visible paths and not the transparent space of the SVG square*/}
                    <g class='svgtest'>                    
                        <path id='state1' onMouseOver={testShowStateId('state 1')} d='M 0 0 L 6 0 L 8 4 L 2 4 Z' stroke='blue' stroke-width='0.1' />
                    </g>
                    <g class='svgtest'>                    
                        <path id='state2' onMouseOver={testShowStateId('state 2')} d='M 6 0 L 11 0 L 13 4 L 8 4 Z' stroke='green' stroke-width='0.1' />
                    </g>
                    <g class='svgtest'>                    
                        <path id='state3' onMouseOver={testShowStateId('state 3')} d='M 2 4 L 0 8 L 6 8 L 8 4 Z' stroke='purple' stroke-width='0.1' />
                    </g>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
    )

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75421547/svg-path-on-click-event

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SVG Path On Click Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75421547/svg-path-on-click-event)

Comment: Just change on click to onmouseover

Comment: First of, thanks for the answers :D. I tried that but It didn´t work. I´m using states and effects so I cannot use the App.js as a class instead of a function so adding event listeners with the the componentDidMount was not possible (as far as I know), I tried changing the events too and checked the questions you posted but nothing worked.

But for some reason I found that changing onMouseOver={testShowStateId('state 1')} to onMouseOver={ ()=> {testShowStateId('state 1')}} worked like magic, I don´t know why